# Listing public methods on a class without creating an instance

Tags: java

The Test Framework I'm using has a rather strange way of adding tests to a Test Suite, as follows:

```
public TestSuiteAll() {
    super("TestSuiteAll")

    this.addTest(new TestTypeOld("TEST_EXECUTION"));
    this.addTest(new TestTypeOld("TEST_COMPLETION_1"));
    this.addTest(new TestTypeOld("TEST_COMPLETION_2"));

    this.addTest(new TestTypeNew("TEST_NEW"));
}
```

where "TEST_EXECUTION" is for example, the name of the function in the TestTypeOld class to call.

I really don't like this design but I'm stuck with it. How can I list all the functions in TestTypeOld so that I can add all of them?

I've see some examples where something like this is done:

```
TestTypeOld testTypeOld = new TestTypeOld("");
Class testTypeOldClass = testTypeOld.getClass();
Method[] methods = testTypeOldClass.getMethods();
```

but this seems really long winded. Is there another way of doing this where I don't need to create a instance of TestTypeOld.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this:

```
Method[] methods = TestTypeOld.class.getMethods();
```

Here's a working example with `java.util.List`:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Method[] methods = List.class.getMethods();
    for(Method method : methods) {
        System.out.println(method.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
TestTypeOld.class.getMethods();
```

The `.class` operator retrieves a Class instance representing the given class.

Answer (score 1):

How about just using

```
Methods[] methods = TestTypeOld.class.getMethods();
```

Then you won't have to create an instance of `TestTypeOld`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Reflection Api
Example:

```
Methods[] methods = TestTypeOld.class.getMethods();
```